# ebpf program: garbage value on reading system call argument

Tags: ebpf

I was trying to write an ebpf prpgram which would read the tablename whenever an iptables command is executed and update the table name in the map. Say "iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT", it should update filter as tablename.

However the program doesnt seem to work and I am getting garbage whenever an iptables cmd is executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, char[XT_TABLE_MAXNAMELEN]);
    __uint(max_entries ,1);
} event_table_map SEC(".maps");


struct ipt_replace {
        /* Which table. */
        char name[XT_TABLE_MAXNAMELEN];
        /* The entries (hang off end: not really an array). */
        char rest[0];
};

SEC("raw_tracepoint/sys_enter")
int trace_setsockopt(struct bpf_raw_tracepoint_args *ctx) {

    // Extract arguments from the syscall

    unsigned long syscall_id = ctx->args[1];
    volatile struct pt_regs *regs;
    volatile const char *pathname;
    if (syscall_id != __NR_setsockopt) {
       return 0;
    }

    regs = (struct pt_regs *)ctx->args[0];
    int sockfd, level, optname ;
    struct ipt_replace *repl_ptr;
    bpf_probe_read(&sockfd, sizeof(int), (void *)&PT_REGS_PARM1(regs));  // Socket file descriptor
    bpf_probe_read(&level, sizeof(int), (void *)&PT_REGS_PARM2(regs));
    bpf_probe_read(&optname, sizeof(int), (void *)&PT_REGS_PARM3(regs));
    bpf_probe_read(&repl_ptr, sizeof(repl_ptr), (void *)&PT_REGS_PARM4(regs));

    // Check if the setsockopt is for IPTABLES-related socket options
    if (level == SOL_IP && optname == IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE) {
        int event = 1;
        struct ipt_replace repl;
        unsigned int map_id = 0;
        char *map_value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&event_table_map, &map_id);
        if (!map_value)
            return 0;
        // Read the IPT_REPLACE structure from user space
        if (bpf_probe_read(&repl, sizeof(repl), repl_ptr) == 0) {
            bpf_probe_read_str(map_value,XT_TABLE_MAXNAMELEN, repl.name);
            return 0;
        }
         bpf_probe_read_str(map_value, XT_TABLE_MAXNAMELEN, "fail");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
sudo bpftool map dump id 890
[{
        "key": 0,
        "value": [72,61,1,-16,-1,-1,115,1,-61,72,-117,13,-106,58,44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ]
    }
]
```

I should have received "filter" as the value.